# React Native: How to fetch after a time, like 24h hours?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i want to fetch after 24 hours so the user gets new recipes from the app. now i call it when the screen gets rendered but i want it to fetch after certain amount of time as example 24 hours, i need a function that counts the time even when the app is closed. is there a way to do this ?

```html
async function getUserData() {
    var userData = await firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).get();
    var labels = []
    userData.data().ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
      labels.push(ingredient.label)
    })
    userData.data()
    setUserIngredients(labels)
    fetchRecipes(labels)
  }


  function fetchRecipes(userIngredients) {
    var url = "https://europe-west3-cookingapp-b71aa.cloudfunctions.net/fetchRecipes?userIngredients=" + userIngredients.join('+') + "&idToken=" + user.idToken
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET"
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        responseJson = JSON.parse(responseJson)
        if (responseJson) {
          var newRecipes = []
          for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            const hit = responseJson.hits[Math.floor(Math.random() * responseJson.hits.length)]
            const newRecipe = {
              id: hit.recipe.uri,
              image: hit.recipe.image,
              label: hit.recipe.label,
              time: hit.recipe.totalTime,
            }
            newRecipes.unshift(newRecipe)
          }
          setIsLoading(false);
          setUserRecipes(newRecipes)
        }
        else {
          console.log("Fehler")
        }
      })
  }
```

this is my function right now

Answer (score 1):

check react-native-background-fetch : https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch

Comment: im using expo on ios so i got no xcode is there any other way or does it work with expo ? and i dont wanna do it with minutes more like every time when 0:00 a clock hits

Comment: i dont have much experience with expo sorry. An idea could be scheduling push notifications in the time you want, and when a notification is clicked you fetch your data.

Comment: You can use https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to save the time of current fetch execution into storage using AsyncStorage. Then when your apps is launched, check for the storage value and calculate the diff time. If it mets your condition, then reexecute your calling function.

Comment: ok i thought about this too. i will try it this way i think